MySQL Lead function returns NULL
I have this MySQL table:



id
Name




1
Spanish


2
French


3
German



I am using this statement:
SELECT id, Name, Lead(Name) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS 'next' from MyTable WHERE Name='French'

The expected result is this:



id
Name
next




2
French
German



The result is this:



id
Name
next




2
French
(NULL)




It is because there is no "next" record for id=2.  There's only one.  Perhaps you didn't really want the OVER clause?  What were you expecting here?

Tim, from what I have read, 'Over' is a mandatory part of  the 'Lead' function. Ordered by 'id', the next row should be 'German'.

@Cymro LEAD is calculated after WHERE.

Use HAVING name = 'French' to perform the filter after getting the result set.

@Barmar Won't help. The resultset is formed after HAVING is applied (and its creation takes into account this HAVING clause effect).

Thanks for the comments. The question is why it is not working. I am following the syntax as far as I can see. An example with the same syntax is here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WF_LEAD.html

@Cymro You make it sound like it should work because you have followed the syntax, and that the comments are marginally relevant. In fact it is working exactly as it should, and exactly as it is documented to work. Same is true for all other window functions. See the first three paragraphs of https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_Window_functions.html.

@GSerg, it would be helpful to the community if you provided a working solution. Thanks. That's why we're here right? To help each other.

I'm not an SQL expert, but this works:
With e AS (
    SELECT id, Name, Lead(Name) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS 'next' from MyTable 
) SELECT Id, Name, next FROM e WHERE Name='French'

There may be more efficient solutions, but since the table is about languages I don't expect it to contain millions of records. Therefore I think performance will hardly be an issue.
/Edit:
This code does the same and I suppose that it will be indeed more efficient for large tables since it will not first calculate all 'next' fields for the entire table:
SELECT d.*, e.Next
    FROM MyTable d OUTER APPLY
    (SELECT TOP(1) Name AS Next
    FROM Mytable e 
    WHERE e.Id > d.Id
    ORDER BY Id
    ) AS e 
    WHERE d.Name = 'French'


That worked. Would have been cool to have a solution in a single select in line with the official syntax, but thanks nontheless.

@Cymro "The official 'Lead'" works exactly as it should. The function would be utterly useless if it was calculated before WHERE. Same for all other window functions. It is your expectations that are wrong, not the result of the function or its documentation.

@Cymro, I think you don't get GSerg's point: your code first selects a data set where Language = 'French' (containing only 1 record), and then calculates 'next' (which does not exist for a set of 1 record).

@Lex. you didn't even use 'Lead' in your solution, which supports my statement that the official SQL syntax for the Lead function is crap. I got -3 points for this? I should be a hero.

The official syntax for LEAD is pathetic. It should be just like in my question, just like it is for other SQL functions. Example here: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_sum.asp

@Cymro, SUM  works just like LEAD,: the function is applied after the WHERE clause. Calling that crap is a matter of opinion..

Lex, I think SUM, AVG, MAX etc. all use a logical syntax, different to that from LAG and LEAD. LAG and LEAD should use this same syntax, but they don't.  https://learnsql.com/blog/aggregate-functions-in-where-clause/

Cymro, you seem to still don't get it. All of these functions operate on the set that is selected by the where clause. All of them. But you want LAG and LEAD to operate on the entire table and afterwards select a subset.
